# emscripten llvm-link sanity test error

Tags: llvm, emscripten

I am trying to install emscripten and i have installed clang,node but when i am running emcc command it is showing an error **Cannot find /usr/bin/llvm-link, check the paths in ~/.emscripten**  . I have installed llvm-3.2 and it has created llvm-link-3.2 file in /usr/bin directory but still this error is coming .

I think llvm-link is hardcoded some where in the code but not able to find where it is.

I have even successfully created the required ~/.emscripten file.

My os is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you will have to add `LLVM_ADD_VERSION = "3.2"` to your `~/.emscripten` file.

Comment: In future it should fallback to the expected LLVM version. Perhaps in a few months ;)

Comment: It's "3.4" at the moment